# Browser attempts to load JS file from invalid address, when accessing razor page through URL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have set a razor page as the landing page for my application:

```
options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Home","/Home/Index", "");
```

My pages are all contained in areas, so in order to access them by url more easily I wanted to avoid writing the additional area name, so from Home/Home/page to Home/Index:

```
options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRouteModelConvention("Home", "/Home/Index", model =>
{
    foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
    {
        selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
        {
            Template = new string(selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.SkipWhile(c => c != '/').Skip(1).ToArray()),
        };
    }
});
```

I also modified my app settings:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        template: "{area=Home}/{page=Index}");
});
```

I removed all the other mapRoutes, including controller routing, etc.

After I added this snippet I tried accessing the pages by /Home/Index, and it worked, however my js scripts are not loading and thus not functioning. Then I removed the aforementioned option and attempted to access the page by Home/Home/Index and my scripts were still not loading. They do load property if I use the anchors I have set up:

```
<a class="nav-bar-brand" asp-area="Home" asp-page="/Home/Index">...</a>
```

The script file is included in the Layout:

```
<script src="js/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The problem appears to be that the browser is looking for the file in the wrong place, this is the Request URL that the General header contains "https://localhost/Home/Home/js/site.js", while in reality the proper address is "https://localhost/js/site.js", why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="**~/**js/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You must update your code thats. (

> **/**

or

> **~/**

get starting on domain root folder)